# How to pass a struct into a function

Tags: c, function, struct, parameter-passing

Could anyone tell me explain, how to pass struct into a function? I've tried to put my sorting into a function, and pass my struct into it

```
typedef struct
{
    int weight;
    int price;
    Color color;
    Equip equip;
}Cars;

Cars automobil[5]; 

sort_cars(&automobil[NUMBER_OF_CARS]);

void sort_cars(struct Cars*automobil[NUMBER_OF_CARS]){
    int i,j;
    CarsmobilOne={};
    for(j=0; j<NUMBER_OF_CARS-1; j++)
    {
        for (i=0; i<NUMBER_OF_CARS-1; i++){
            if (automobil[i]->weight < automobil[i+1]->weight)
            {
                continue;

            }else{
                mobilOne = automobil[i];
                automobil[i] = automobil[i+1];
                automobil[i+1] = mobilOne;
            }
        }
    }
```

I got this error "incompatible types when assigning to type 'Cars' from type 'struct Cars*'|" I've tried to do passing the struct as people do in the Internet

Comment: Sigh,  on which line? Please post a [MCVE].

Comment: on this line:

    mobilOne = automobil[i];

Comment: You don't define a `struct Cars` anywhere in your code

Comment: Change `struct Cars` to `Cars`.  You never defined `Cars` as a structure tag, only as a `typedef`.

Comment: An error is about how you declare the struct. You use a typedef to create a `struct Cars`but you are giving to the function a `struct Cars`not `Cars` that is the struct you created.

Comment: @KrzysztofHeigel please [edit] your questikon and put all relevant information _there_.

Comment: The line `sort_cars(&automobil[NUMBER_OF_CARS]);` should not be compiling since it is outside any function (and because `NUMBER_OF_CARS` is undefined).  It is highly unlikely that you should be passing an array of pointers to the function.  Certainly, you can't sort the array `Cars automobil[5];` with that function signature.  You'd need an intermediary array of pointers to be able to do so.

Comment: The formal parameter is also an array of pointers to `Cars` (technically a pointer to a pointer and not an array at all) but you're passing a `Cars *`.

Comment: `mobilOne` isn't declared in the code you posted. Please read and understand this (it's essential): [mcve].

Answer (score 3):

> I've tried to do passing the struct as people do in the Internet

No, you have not. You have tried to invent a new syntax for passing an array, but unfortunately it is **not** the way arrays are passed in C language.

In C language, arrays do decay to pointers when they are passed as parameters to functions, so people usually pass the actual length along with the array.

So you should use:

```
void sort_cars(Cars*automobil, int number_of_cars){
    int i,j;
    Cars mobilOne={};
    for(j=0; j<number_of_cars-1; j++)
    {
        for (i=0; i<number_of_cars-1; i++){
            if (automobil[i]->weight < automobil[i+1]->weight)
            {
                continue;

            }else{
                mobilOne = automobil[i];
                automobil[i] = automobil[i+1];
                automobil[i+1] = mobilOne;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And call it:

```
sort_cars(automobil, 5);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
int carsSort(const void *a, const void *b) {
    return ((Cars *) a)->weight - ((Cars *) b)->weight;
}

void sortThem(Cars autom[]) {
    qsort(autom, NC, sizeof *autom, carsSort);
}

int main() {
    Cars automobil[NC];

    // Initialiase automobil here
    sortThem(automobil);

    for (int i = 0; i < NC; ++i)
    printf("%d\n", automobil[i].weight);
}
```

Remember one of the many wise sayings of K&R: "When an array name is passed to a function, what is passed is the location of the beginning of the array".

Inside sortThem() "autom" is a variable whose value is the address of automobil[0].

John

Comment: It's nice to see some functional programming in C. Code re-use is good.